Change Orientation and Order of Items in Legend ggplot2 r
Is there a way to change the orientation of the items in the legend of ggplot2 chart?
I have a series of boxplots where I would like the individual items to oriented vertically opposed to horizontally. Additionally I would like the "Top" item to be the first item in the legend.
I've tried adding legend.direction = "vertical" to the theme clause.
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Posemo, y=Target.Lab, fill=Target.Lab)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="right", legend.direction = "vertical") + 
  labs(y = "Performance", x = "Warmth", title = "Top and Bottom Performing Candidates by Warmth", fill = 'Target.Lab')+ 
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Top", "Bottom")) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Warmth")

This get me to here:

